# Install DISM powershell module on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, powershell, dism

Is it possible to install the DISM powershell module on Windows 7 (with SP1) without installing the Windows ADK which requires ~6GB of disk space?

If so, what are the steps to achieve this?

It seems that all options require to install the Windows ADK...

Comment: why is installing ADK no option? if you want this feature install it.

Comment: @magicandre1981 because I don't want 6GB of extra stuff installed :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What would you say to a solution that needs only **96 MB** instead of 6 GB?

Do the following:

1. Grab the WADK web installer from [its home page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install)
2. Run it with administrative privileges
3. On the first page, choose to install WADK.
4. On the next pages, which involves choosing an installation location, accepting the license agreement, or helping Microsoft by letting collect diagnostics data, do whatever you want.
5. On the component selection page, **uncheck all installation options except Deployment Tools**.
6. Proceed with installation. The download size would be 101 MB and the installation size is almost the same.

**Remember:** WADK is the only way of legitimately installing DISM module. Therefore, in this website, nobody will suggest anything else.

Comment: You also need to make sure the module's parent folder is in your `PSModulePath`. That means you most likely will need to add: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\DISM` to the `PSModulePath` environment variable. If that folder doesn't exist, the module's filename you can search for is `Microsoft.Dism.PowerShell.dll`.

Comment: Sincerely, the link you gave it's a mess! Can you please provide the exactly location/name specifiying Windows 7 not 11, win10, win8. Thx!